# Setting up sass for a project

Tags: node.js, sass

I am trying to set up a style.scss file to output into style.css.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "soumghosh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and my gruntfile.js looks like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';
  grunt.initConfig({
    echo: {
      one: { message: 'one has changed' },
      two: { message: 'two has changed' },
      wait: { message: 'I waited 2s', wait: 2000 },
      interrupt: { message: 'I want to be interrupted', wait: 5000 },
      fail: { fail: 1, message: 'This task should fail', wait: 1000 }
    },
    watch: {
      one: {
        files: ['lib/one.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
        tasks: 'echo:one',
      },
      two: {
        files: ['lib/two.js'],
        tasks: ['echo:two'],
      },
      wait: {
        files: ['lib/wait.js'],
        tasks: ['echo:wait'],
      },
      interrupt: {
        files: ['lib/interrupt.js'],
        tasks: ['echo:interrupt'],
        options: { interrupt: true },
      },
      fail: {
        files: ['lib/fail.js'],
        tasks: ['echo:fail'],
      },
    },
  });
  // Load the echo task
  grunt.loadTasks('../tasks');
  // Load this watch task
  grunt.loadTasks('../../../tasks');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['echo']);
};
```

I guess what my confusion is how to I initiate the process to look into a specific directory to compile the scss file. Should I be doing something in my terminal to start a script? I am fairly new to node and thats why I am getting a bit confused with this.

Comment: You need to kick it off, somehow.  Given the [main] variable in your package file I'd guess:  node index.js

Comment: I guess my question would be why not use a pre processor...does the same job..something like koala

Comment: Sass *is* a preprocessor.  Koala is just a GUI.